# Find an integrable function in $t$ that bounds $\vert e^{-t}t^{a} \frac{t^h - 1}{h} \vert$ for all $a,t > 0$ and $\vert h \vert < h_0$.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, derivatives, gamma-function

I think I have found an answer to this which I have given at the end but is there a better answer?

I am trying to prove differentiability of gamma function $\Gamma(z)$ for $Re(z) > 1$ using dominated convergence theorem.
So for differentiability, $$ \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\Gamma(z+h) - \Gamma(z)}{h} $$ must converge. To prove this, I want to be able to take the limit inside the integral as shown below:
$$ \lim_{h\to 0} \int^{\infty}_0 e^{-t}t^{z-1} \frac{t^h - 1}{h} dt =  \int^{\infty}_0 \lim_{h\to 0}  e^{-t}t^{z-1} \frac{t^h - 1}{h} dt $$
which is possible, according to Dominated Convergence Theorem, if the integrand is bounded by an **integrable function $\alpha(t,z)$**, i.e.
$$ \Bigg | e^{-t}t^{z-1} \frac{t^h - 1}{h}  \Bigg | < \alpha(t,z)$$ for all $\vert h \vert < h_0$ (for some real positive $h_0$) and $$ \int^{\infty}_0 \alpha(t,z) dt < \infty $$
This is equivalent to finding an integrable function $\alpha(t,a)$ such that $$ \Bigg | e^{-t}t^{a} \frac{t^h - 1}{h}  \Bigg | < \alpha(t,a)$$ for real $a>0$. So the goal is finding such a function $\alpha$.

**Edit: The answer that I had given initially was wrong.** I was treating $h$ as a real number instead of a complex.

Here is another solution (**edited**) that I found:

$$ \Bigg | \frac{t^h - 1}{h} \Bigg | = \Bigg |\frac{e^{h\log t} - 1}{h} \Bigg | $$
$$ = \Bigg | \frac{h\log t + \frac{(h\log t)^2}{2!} +  \frac{(h\log t)^3}{3!}+ \cdots}{h} \Bigg | $$
$$ \leq \vert \log t (1 + \frac{(h\log t)^1}{2!} +\frac{(h\log t)^2}{3!} + \cdots)\vert $$
$$= \vert \log t \vert (1+  \frac{(\vert h\log t \vert)^1}{2!} + \frac{(\vert h\log t \vert)^2}{3!} + \cdots) $$
$$ \leq \vert \log t \vert (1+ \vert h \log t \vert + \frac{(\vert h\log t \vert)^2}{2!} + \cdots) $$
$$= \vert \log t \vert e^{\vert h\log t \vert } \leq \vert \log t \vert e^{h_0\vert\log t \vert } $$
for all $ \lvert h \rvert \leq h_0 $.
Hence, the required function is
$$ \alpha(t,a) = e^{-t}t^{a} \vert \log t \vert e^{h_0 \vert \log t \vert }$$
It can be shown that its integral w.r.t. $t$ exists and is finite.

Answer (score 2):

There cannot be an intergable function $g$ on $(0,\infty)$ such that $|\frac {t^{h}-1} h | \leq g(t)$ for all $t>0$ and all $h$ with $|h|<h_0$. For, it you take limit as $h \to 0$ you will get $|\log (t)| \leq g(t)$ for all $t$ and $|\log (t)|$ is not integrable.

Comment: Okay, so I can't find any integrable g(t). That means I should go back to looking for $\alpha(t)$. Could you help me with that?

Answer (score -1):

Hint : Usually to show the derivability of the gamma function, you use theorems of dominated convergence. You first derive the function under the integral and show that it can be dominated.

Comment: Why would I get negative review for something absolutely correct ?

Comment: I am sorry. When I said bounded convergence theorem, I was thinking of dominated convergence theorem. So the solution I am looking for is actually through this method. But I am unable to find the function which dominates my integrand.

Comment: Yes but what I tell you is to is : let’s call $f(x,t)$ thé function under the integral. $f$ is differentiable$ with respect to x. And then you can dominate the derivative of f with respect to x independently of x to show the differentiablity of gamma.

Comment: I added an answer to the question as an edit. I think this is what you were pointing towards. Thanks for the help.

Comment: No you are just doing things too complicated. Do you know any theorem on the continuity of an integral as an application of the dominated convergence theorem ? I don’t see where you computed the derivative of your integrand. You should not need any $h$ in your proof.

Comment: Could you give me the whole solution done your way?

Comment: No. I took the time to answer you and give you details. I said three times to compute the derivative of your integrand and you didn’t even do it.